# How to use @produces in JSON object spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, annotations

Is it possible to use @produces for JSON objects in spring boot? Or is there another way to implement this:

```
JSONObject J_Session = new JSONObject();
J_Session.put("SESSION_ID_J", session_jid);
J_Session.put("J_APP", "J");
J_Session.put("REST_ID_J", rest_id);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the question, you just want to know if you can use `@Produces` annotation to give json response in Spring rest API?

Comment: Use POJOs. They should be supported be default.

Comment: @Chaitanya yes that's it. can you give example pls

Comment: @peeskillet can you give example based on my post?

Comment: @Chaitanya I'm kind of new to java, how do I convert this based on your comment?

Comment: @CarminaCastañeto, I have given answer to this post explaining how it can be done, see below and also a link that gives a complete working example.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example:

**RestController class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.websystique.springboot.model.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestApiController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    public List<User> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(new User(1, "Sam", 30, 70000));
        users.add(new User(2, "Tom", 40, 50000));
        users.add(new User(3, "Jerome", 45, 30000));
        users.add(new User(4, "Silvia", 50, 40000));
        return users;
    }
}
```

The attribute `produces = { "application/json" }` automatically converts List collection to json response.

Below is the POJO class.

**User Pojo class**

```
public class User {

    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private int age;
    
    private double salary;

    public User(){
    }
    
    public User(long id, String name, int age, double salary){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

**Sample JSON response:**

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Sam",
      "age":30,
      "salary":70000
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Tom",
      "age":40,
      "salary":50000
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Jerome",
      "age":45,
      "salary":30000
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Silvia",
      "age":50,
      "salary":40000
   }
]
```

Follow this [link](http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-api-example/) for a complete detailed example with CRUD operations.

The above code is from this link itself, I just modified the controller part to make it simple.

Comment: Your Pojo keyword ended 2 hours of debugging of why spring boot doesn't produce json object. I was using non-POJO class. Thanks!

Comment: Could shorten this to `@GetMapping(value = "/user/", produces = { "application/json" })`

Comment: And of course, return `List.of`...

Answer (score 3):

there are a few errors , dont use JSONObject , only if is necesary (try to use Gson library), for convention the variable J_Session the first letter must be in lower case like jSession , if your class have the annotation @RestController you dont need to use @ResponseBody in the method only if the class is marked like @Controller; there is my example for a class with @Controller annotation instead @RestController annotation, with this your JSONObject is not longer necesary , another thing , try lo read about of differences between pojos and beans , and always try to nulify yours variables after use them (sorry about my english)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> insertSomething(@RequestBody String body){
    ArrayList<String> listOfStrings=null;
    if (body != null){
        listOfStrings= new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfStrings.add (body);
        listOfStrings.add("somethin else");//Json Object because the "produces"
    }else{
        listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();// empty Json object to avoid null exception in client side (in my case Angular 6)
    }

    return listOfStrings;
}
```